# How to emulate a postman post in c#

Tags: http, postman, httpclient, send

I need to write the C# equivalent of a working PostMan operation. I know it is simple, but I'm stuck! Implementation via HttpClient, WebClient, RestSharp is preferable. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the code in Postman, generate for `RestSharp` is supported.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: Tony Yip --- You are a life saver. The answer was right in front of me (and I looked at it several times) but I could not see it. Thank-you